# Angular interceptor for switching requests

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I want to create an interceptor (or any other solution that will affect all the services), that will hold the POST requests for ~300ms and in case there are new POST requests in that time gap, will perform `switchMap` on them.

Something like that:

```
@Injectable()
export class DebounceInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.method != HttpMethod.Post) {
      return next.handle(req);
    } else {
      return of().pipe(switchMap(() => next.handle(req)));
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, but the agenda is to handle all requests in case the user double click a save button or any other case that shouldn't happen.

**Edit:**

That should work but the `intercept()` function must have a returned value. Any thoughts on that would solve it

```
  test: Subject<any>;
  constructor() {
    this.test.pipe(
      debounceTime(5000),
      switchMap(({ req, next }: { req: HttpRequest<any>; next: HttpHandler }) => next.handle(req))
    );
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.method != HttpMethod.Post) {
      return next.handle(req);
    } else {
      this.test.next({ req, next });
    }
  }
```

Comment: In order to implement that you would need to store all requests. I can imagine some service that holds a list of requests and start time for each one. Then you would call this service every time to check if the same request exist and suppress or switchMap it. But for me it's too complicated, why not just handle it on a higher level - in a component or service?

Comment: Thank you! I though about storing all the requests or having a subject and subscribing to it inside the interceptor but as you said it's too hacky.. Handling it at a lower level such as the component or some service, requires all the components or services to have this kind of implementation. Also, It depends on the developer to use that implementation instead of just doing it behind the scenes.

Comment: Complexity is not the only thing. In my opinion HTTP interceptor shouldn't have such logic - it shouldn't "know" about save buttons or any other UI elements. It should only work with the requests.

Comment: I would make the components ( and yes, developers too ) responsible for their actions. If you want to incapsulate for example this save button - you can make a component for it. It would debounce the click requests and emit them only after 300ms.